# React native: Is it possible to get react native componet size in Java?

Tags: java, android, react-native, imageview

I have created custom native component as below for Android's ImageView.

```
public class ImageViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<ImageView> {

public static final String REACT_CLASS = "ImageView";

@Override
public String getName() {
  return REACT_CLASS;
}

@Override
protected ImageView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(reactContext);
  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 200))
  return imageView;
}

@ReactProp(name="src")
public void setSrc(ImageView imageView, String src) {
    try {
        Bitmap bm = ImageUtilConverter.convert(src); // base64 to bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {

    }
}
}
```

In JavaScript:
    import ImageView from './ImageView'

```
<ImageView
    style={{width: deviceWidth, height: deviceHeight}} 
    src={this.state.selected} // base64 data
/>
```

Now I want to get height and width of the component in Java, so that I can set height and width in imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 200)).

Is it possible to get component size in Java?

Comment: you can pass hieght/width from javascript to you java's component

Comment: @KishanVaghela how to do it? Using prop's?

Comment: yes. same you did using 'src'